# How do I loop through all rows and send one email with all row data?

Tags: google-apps-script

My current script is able to send an email, but it sends multiple email with one row of data in each email. I want the script to be able to send one email with all rows of data.

```
function tazEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1naSWINA8_uxeLUsj0lFntqILyDj2nirb56uvkBel79Y").getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CRM Feedback");

  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var manager_email = "email@email.org.au";

  for( var i = 1; i< data.length;i++ ) {

    var timestamp =             data[i][0];
    var requesterEmail =        data[i][1];
    var starRating =            data[i][2];
    var requestCatergory =      data[i][3];
    var description =           data[i][4];
    var label =                 data[i][5];
    var ticketId =              data[i][6];
    var comment =               data[i][7];
    var status =                data[i][8];
    var priority =              data[i][9];
    var office =                data[i][10];
    var message = "";

    var check = data[i][11];

    if (check == "complete"){
      continue;
    }else {

      var subject = "CT IT feedback - ";
      var body = "<body>";
      message +=
      "<p><b>Timestamp by: </b>" + data[i][0] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Requester Email: </b>" + data[i][1] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Star Rating: </b>" + data[i][2] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Request Category: </b>" + data[i][3] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Description: </b>" + data[i][4] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Label: </b>" + data[i][5] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Ticket ID: </b>" + data[i][6] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + data[i][7] + "</p>" +
      "<p><b>Status: </b>" + data[i][8] + "</p><br><br>";

      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: manager_email,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});



    }



  }


}
```

Comment: Why do you send the email inside for loop and expect it to send a single email?

Comment: thanks for the pickup, but how would I define the values if it's outside the loop

Comment: @tomhutn - would you mind sharing the sheet? Even an anonymised version should help with assessing the exact solution based on your use case.

Comment: Define the values inside loop and send the email outside for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function tazEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1naSWINA8_uxeLUsj0lFntqILyDj2nirb56uvkBel79Y").getSheetByName("Sheet3");

  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CRM Feedback");

  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var manager_email = "email@email.org.au";
  var message = "";
  var subject = "CT IT feedback - ";
  var body = "<body>"; // Don't think this is being used. May be deleted.

  for( var i = 1; i< data.length;i++ ) {

    var timestamp =             data[i][0];
    var requesterEmail =        data[i][1];
    var starRating =            data[i][2];
    var requestCatergory =      data[i][3];
    var description =           data[i][4];
    var label =                 data[i][5];
    var ticketId =              data[i][6];
    var comment =               data[i][7];
    var status =                data[i][8];
    var priority =              data[i][9];
    var office =                data[i][10];

    var check = data[i][11];

    if (check == "complete"){
      continue;
    }else {

      message +=
        "<p><b>Timestamp by: </b>" + data[i][0] + "</p>" +
          "<p><b>Requester Email: </b>" + data[i][1] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Star Rating: </b>" + data[i][2] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Request Category: </b>" + data[i][3] + "</p>" +
                "<p><b>Description: </b>" + data[i][4] + "</p>" +
                  "<p><b>Label: </b>" + data[i][5] + "</p>" +
                    "<p><b>Ticket ID: </b>" + data[i][6] + "</p>" +
                      "<p><b>Comment: </b>" + data[i][7] + "</p>" +
                        "<p><b>Status: </b>" + data[i][8] + "</p><br><br>";
    }
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: manager_email,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```